# One input file - multiple output files

Tags: haml

Is it possible to have one input HAML file which produces multiple output files in one folder.

Request is to have one price list for products with links to individual product descriptions which is basically the same html file with small differences.

Is this possible ONLY in HAML?

Comment: It's possible, depending on what those differences are and what you're trying to accomplish. Clarify your question with some code, and we may be able to help you further.

Comment: I'm still learning HAML, but with the other tool for HTML pages (ppwizard), i have one input file which has multiple output directives: #output "pricelist.html" and manny #output "prod001.html", and it produces manny files. I used ppwizard before, but HAML syntax is much nicer... Is there a command to change current output file? I dont need a solution, just a little "nudge" in the right direction :)

Comment: although it is possible to code in HAML you are probably better of parameteriszing your haml file and calling it several times for each output.